# Email text encoded with ASCII+1 scheme?

Tags: email, encoding, ascii

Something extremely strange is happening to me. I receive an email newsletter (about film news) and recently most of its text has suddenly begun to look like gibberish.

The corresponding article, directly on the website sending the newsletter, displays fine.

Comparing the two, I have found very surprisingly that where the original article shows A, the email shows B. B is displayed as C etc, in the email each character's ASCII code is exactly the original article's letter + 1 !?

So what should be "Cable" in the article is actually displayed "Dbcmf" in the email.

This happens if I read the gmail account on Chrome but NOT on other browsers.

Is there an explanation for this?

Thanks.